# MySQL Cluster 7.4.6 - Analyze table failure on 15m reference table

Tags: mysql, memory, mysql-cluster, optimization, timeout

I'm running MySQL Cluster 7.4.6 on Azure VM's with the following infrastructure:

2 x Mgmt Nodes: Ubuntu 14.10LTS, 2 cores, 3.5GB ram
2 x MySQL API Nodes: Ubuntu 14.10LTS, 2 cores, 3.5GB ram
2 x Data Nodes: Ubuntu 14.10LTS, 4 cores, 7GB ram

Config.ini

```
[TCP DEFAULT]
SendBufferMemory=256K
ReceiveBufferMemory=256K

[ndbd default]
# Options affecting ndbd processes on all data nodes:
ServerPort=14555
NoOfReplicas=2    # Number of replicas
DataMemory=3G
SharedGlobalMemory=256M
DiskPageBufferMemory=1G
IndexMemory=1G
LockPagesInMainMemory=0

MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=50000
MaxNoOfTriggers=4096

#StringMemory=25
MaxNoOfTables=512
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=256
MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes=256
MaxNoOfAttributes=5000
#DiskCheckpointSpeedInRestart=100M
#FragmentLogFileSize=256M
#NoOfFragmentLogFiles=3
#RedoBuffer=8M

#HeartbeatIntervalDbDb=15000
#HeartbeatIntervalDbApi=15000
#TimeBetweenLocalCheckpoints=20
#TimeBetweenGlobalCheckpoints=1000
#TimeBetweenEpochs=100

#TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout=32000

#MemReportFrequency=30
#BackupReportFrequency=30

[ndb_mgmd default]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-cluster  # Directory for MGM node log files

[ndb_mgmd]
nodeid=1
hostname=192.168.2.4            # Hostname or IP address of MGM node

[ndb_mgmd]
nodeid=2
hostname=192.168.2.9            # Hostname or IP address of MGM node

[ndbd]
                                # (one [ndbd] section per data node)
hostname=192.168.2.5            # Hostname or IP address
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files

[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.2.7            # Hostname or IP address
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data   # Directory for this data node's data files

[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.2.6            # Hostname or IP address
                                # (additional mysqld connections can be
                                # specified for this node for various
                                # purposes such as running ndb_restore)

[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.2.8            # Hostname or IP address
                                # (additional mysqld connections can be
                                # specified for this node for various
                                # purposes such as running ndb_restore)
```

Disk space varies, but currently using about 11GB/30GB across each machine.

I have a table as below with ~15m records. Nothing special, just a join table essentially.

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| branch_id  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| range_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

 Indices:  product_id, branch_id, range_id, branch_id+product_id
```

All of my other tables ANALYZE quickly and correctly, returning 'OK'.

When attempting to ANALYZE this table, it always fails prematurely as below after about 60-240s.

```
+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Table                                  | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text                                      |
+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| db1.cat_products_ranges                | analyze | error    | Unknown - internal error 702 during operation |
+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (2 min 19.26 sec)
```

Looking on the interwebs for this error is like finding a needle in a haystack and I'm out of ideas. The manual reference error 702 tells me that there was an attempted request to a non-master. In light of this, I attempted shutting down the non-master data node. The process is still running after 2 hours and I cannot tell whether it's hung or not. The cluster is operational, however.

Can I find out if it's still running or hung?

I have attempted rebuilding the cluster from scratch, literally rebuilding it last night with new VM's on the latest 7.4.6 version and importing the data.

I have attempted dropping the table and re-importing it via SQL, creating manually and importing via < dump.

Interestingly, trying to drop the indices results in **SQL Error (1205): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction** so I cannot attempt that.

Can anyone please shed some light on this or provide some suggestions as to debug? I have done everything I can think of and now at day 3 with no light at the end of the tunnel.

If you need additional details, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29740658/4576237